# C#: UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to modify file inside open VSCode folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, overwrite

I am currently trying to set up a task in VSCode that automatically generates some metadata for the HTML file i am editing, by creating/overwriting a file called "pagMeta.txt". My VSCode directory roughly looks like:

- project
- - `myHtmlFile.html`
- - `pagMeta.txt`
- - metaDataGenerator
- - - bin
- - - - Debug
- - - - - net6.0
- - - - - - `metaDataGenerator.exe`
- - - - - - `metaDataGenerator.dll`
- - - - - - `metaDataGenerator.runtimeConfig.json`

I've then set up the following task in `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "label": "GeneratePageMetaData",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "C://...//project//metaDataGenerator//bin//Debug//net6.0//metaDataGenerator.exe",
    "args": [
      "${file}"
    ],
    "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": true
    },
    "presentation": {
        "reveal":"silent",
        "panel":"shared"
    },
    "problemMatcher": []
},
```

Running this tasks works fine *if* `pagMeta.txt` doesn't already exists, but i'm thrown a UnathorizedAccesException if the file does exist (even if i do not have it open inside of VSCode):

```
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\..\Project\pagMeta.txt' is denied
```

Running the executable without VSCode open also works fine, so it would seem that `pagMeta.txt` is constantly open every time i open the project inside VSCode, preventing other executables from overwriting it. What can I do to fix this?